Slicing certain part of a CPU inside docker container and affine threads to it
I have a Docker Containerized application, which runs IO intensive workloads. The container is assigned 10 CPUs. Is there a way to partly slice one particular CPU ?
Is there a way to partition these 10 CPUs such that 9.7 and 0.3 CPUs where 9.7 CPUs are available for all processes in the container, and we reserve 0.3 (or 30% of 1 CPU) for certain threads/processes ? This is so that when IO workload is running at peak, it consumes only 9.7 CPUs, but those threads still remain unaffected by this heavy load.

Some ideas for a linux based system with ionice and taskset:
Try changing the IO scheduling priority for the IO only processes to a lower number. See ionice command http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice
The IO priority for BEST EFFORT ranges from 0 to 7 (0 being highest).
Maybe, use IO scheduling of IDLE for the non IO specific processes.
Maybe, use IO scheduling of REALTIME for the IO specific processes.
CPU affinity via taskset command, see taskset command http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset
